# TFS/Eclipse/Selenium: When I import project from TFS to Eclipse it will not be UFT8 encoding which leads to infinite errors

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, tfs

I have a project that is exported to TFS using Eclipse TFS plug-in when I re import the the project from TFS to eclipse into another machine it will not take the UFT8 encoding.

Note: My eclipse is configured to have UFT8 encoding from the text editor

Comment: So what is your Question?

Comment: How to import project from TFS to eclipse using UFT8 encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you import your project from TFS to eciplse, you have to run one program using UF8 encoding after that you can import your project from TFS

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below steps to set the default file encoding in Eclipse:

- Window > Preferences > General > Content Types, set UTF-8 as the
  default encoding for all content types.
- Window > Preferences > General > Workspace, set "Text file encoding"
  to "Other : UTF-8".
- You can also set the default encoding in `eclipse.ini`: Open
  eclipse.ini in your eclipse home directory --> put the line
  `-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` at the end of the file --> Save

Then import the project again.

For the projects which already imported, you can right click the Project --> **Properties** and select **Resource** on the left side menu. You can now change the Text-file encoding to whatever you wish.

This article for your reference : [Unicode/UTF-8 in your Eclipse Java projects](https://stijndewitt.com/2010/05/05/unicode-utf-8-in-eclipse-java/)

[image]